# Error with docker pull command - mediaType error

Tags: docker, ubuntu

I'm trying to pull Ubuntu and getting the following error.

> mediaType in manifest should be 'application/vnd.docker.distribution.manifest.v2+json' not 'application/vnd.oci.image.manifest.v1+json'

I'm running Docker version 20.10.12, build 20.10.12-0ubuntu2~18.04.1

This issue has only recently appeared.

I've just tried pulling Redis, and that worked.

Any ideas?

Comment: **1.** What is your platform architecture? **2.** which is the version of the ubuntu image you pulled? *It would be better to list the information in detail, it may make some help*

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem

```
 docker pull bytebase/bytebase:1.17.0
1.17.0: Pulling from bytebase/bytebase
mediaType in manifest should be 'application/vnd.docker.distribution.manifest.v2+json' not 'application/vnd.oci.image.manifest.v1+json'
```

Comment: I solved this problem by upgrading the docker version to the latest (23.0.5)